# Embedding Moxtra Chat Into Blogs

Tags: embed

Is it possible to get an embed code for the chat history in Moxtra to be able to embed in a blog post? Possibly an iframe code?

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried and give us more detail on your problem!

Comment: It would be great to embed the chat into a blog or WordPress site. For education it would allow students to highlight their progress...

Comment: What have you found till now?

Comment: I've found that there is no way to get an embed code. Like I said, I'm not sure if there is a way, just trying to help out teachers looking to share out student progress. Since the chat is protected to only people sharing the binder, I can imagine that an embed code would be hard to access.

Answer (score 0):

There is a iframe option in the JS SDK according to https://developer.moxtra.com/docs/docs-js-sdk/chat/#conversationview so I think it's possible to embed it into your website.